# R studio graph not appearing in plots window

Tags: graph, plot, rstudio

I am having trouble getting my graphs to appear in the 'plots' window of R studio - once I run the script they appear in a separate R graphics window, separate to R Studio, with the 'plots' tab blank.

Is there a setting or code I should use to change this?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

This has been a consistent problem for many users ever since the last couple updates, myself included. It was apparently fixed with 3.5 version of R, which I haven't updated to, but you didn't mention which version you are running.

Either way, if you're running the most updated version or not, try `getOption("device")` and check the output of that. Per an R support community post, if the output does not say `RStudioGD`, you can use `options(device = "RStudioGD")`.

The NEXT, and more annoying, solution was to uninstall and reinstall RStudio. Many people found that this solved their problem.

If neither of those work work, the only other solution that people were finding is to downgrade your R version to a compatible version unfortunately! It's really annoying, I know!

Hope I could help!